# How can solve ExtJS 4.1 Combobox pageSize bug?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

We have an ExtJS v4.1 combobox and we've bound it to a store and set its pageSize config as follow:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    remoteFilter: true,
    remotePaging: true,
    autoLoad: true
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },
    pageSize: 50,                  //   <= store pageSize
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    store: myStore,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: 'Id',
    pageSize: 20                   //   <= combobo pageSize
});
```

As [documentation says](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) the `pageSize` property of combobox should be used to filter ajax queries sent to the server when `queryMode='remote'`. But what we see is the opposite, and it's only being used to show a paging toolbar at the bottom of the combobox (the first comment of the documentation says so).

But what we really need in this specific case is to override the `pageSize` property of the store, and make combobox's `pageSize` property being used for filtering ajax request.

How can we implement/extend such a feature in combobox? How can we override the store's `pageSize` property in combobox?

Answer (score 2):

pageSize in comboBox is actually a true/false value, despite the documentation.

In javascript, if it's 0, paging toolbar is off, else it's on.

Is this a shared store, or is it just for the combobox?

If shared, then you will want to save the pagesize of the store, change it for the combo when necessary, and then set it back again:

```
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                width: 350,
                store: new MyStore(),
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                pageSize: 2,
                listeners:{
                    beforequery:function(queryEvent){
                        var combo = queryEvent.combo;
                        var store = combo.getStore();
                        var oldPageSize = store.pageSize;
                        store.on('load', function(){
                            this.pageSize = oldPageSize;
                        });
                        store.pageSize = combo.pageSize;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks neil, great idea. I solved is just for not-shared store by overriding its store. but your solution is work for both shared and not-share store I think. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make this work, add parameter/config to the store when instantiating. Here's how I do it

```
store: new Ext.create('MyStore',{pageSize:20}),
pageSize: true
```

Comment: thanks, but when we use sencha mvc on the combo config we just write store name and dont instantiate it. do you any solution for it?

Comment: yes, I also use the Sencha MVC.If you have a `Store`, for example `Ext.define ('MyCompany.store.MyStore', {...})`. We could write in the `combo` `store: new Ext.create ('MyCompany.store.MyStore', {PageSize: 12})`